# JSON Middleware Not Working

Tags: python, django

So what I am trying to do is to catch any HttpErrors thrown and convert them to JSON responses. I created this middleware:

```
from simple_rest.exceptions import HttpError
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

class JSONErrorMiddleware():
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        print 1111
        if not isinstance(exception, HttpError):
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({
                    'status'  : 'error',
                    'message' : exception.message,
                }),
                status=500,
                content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8',
            )

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({
                'status'  : 'error',
                'message' : exception.message,
            }),
            status=exception.status,
            content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8',
        )
```

And added it to my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'proj.middleware.JSONErrorMiddleware',
)
```

When I make a request to an endpoint where HttpError is thrown, the middleware is not used. I just get a text/html response instead of a nice JSON response.

Any idea why?

EDIT: The exception is raised in a custom decorator? Could that be a problem?

Comment: I don't recall the details, but the middleware order is important.  Are you sure that the exception is not being raised after your middleware activates?

Comment: @aquavitae I tried changing order of middleware, it does not help. It still ignores my middleware class. I also removed all middleware I don't need.

Comment: @aquavitae The exception is raised in my custom decorator btw.

Comment: Where's the decorator, and what does it decorate?  Perhaps a bit of code context would help?  Presumably the exception is being handled before it hits your middleware.  Have you tried running it through a debugger?  I assume that the `print 1111` line is never run...